# XMLHttpRequest status is 0 why?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is my code:

```
var xmlhttp;

function HttpObject(str)
{
    //alert("iam in process request");

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert ("xmlhttp");
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        alert ("ms.xmlhttp");        
    }
    else
    {
        XmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }

    alert ("rdystate: " + xmlhttp.readyState);
    alert ("status: "   + xmlhttp.status);
    alert ("Text: "     + xmlhttp.statusText);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = processRequest(); 
    xmlhttp.open("POST",'/CountryTest.do',true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function processRequest()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 0) {
        alert("u r in 0 :: The request is not initialized "); 
    }

    var target = document.getElementById("curlist");
    var res =  xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert(res);
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
    {
        alert("in readystate");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("error in readystate");
    }
}
```

It always displaying `status 0`

`curlist` is id of my country state prog

can any one say me where is problem?

`/CountryTest.do` is the url pattern of the servlet.

Answer (score 3):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = processRequest();
```

You just called `processRequest` *immediately*, and assigned its return value to `onreadystatechange`.

You want to assign the function itself, without calling it.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
 if (xmlhttp.readyState=='4')
 {
  alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
 }
}
```